# How to add extra css in style.css file?

Tags: theming

I want to add extra css for my images (I just want to set `float:left` to them).

I've checked where I need to add my CSS i.e.`<div class="field field-name-field-gallery field-type-image field-label-above">`.

So should I directly add this class name in `style.css` file or should it go somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if style.css is a CSS file that's loaded into your page (either by a module or, more likely, your theme) then that's probably a good place for your custom styles.

If you'd rather have your own file for custom styles though, you can just create a file (e.g. custom.css) in your theme folder, and add a line like this to the theme's .info file:

```
stylesheets[all][] = custom.css
```

Once you clear Drupal's caches you should see the new stylesheet included in all pages using that theme.

Comment: Thanks clive ,I am getting problem that i know class name using fire bug <div class="field field-name-field-gallery field-type-image field-label-above"> , how can i add this into css file ? what would be specific syntax to add it?

Comment: I think the most specific class in that is `.field-name-field-gallery`, give that a try

Comment: Thanks Clive..Its working ..you save my time ,Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should write this to group them together (replaceing the spaces in the class to dots):
field.field-name-field-gallery.field-type-image.field-label-above